# plot by group in shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am trying to make a plot in Shiny and I would like to be able to plot all the data set as well as group data sets based on `by`.  How to get around this? Many thanks in advance. [image]

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)


ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Plot By by"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    sidebarLayout(
        
      sidebarPanel( width = 2, selectInput(inputId = "by", 
                                           label = "dataset by",
                                           choices = c("by.1", "by.2"), 
                                           selected = "by.1")
                    ),

        
        
        
       
        mainPanel(
           plotOutput("distPlot")
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
      
      
      df <- data.frame(dose = c("D0.5", "D1", "D2", "D3", "D4", "D5"),
                       len = c(4.2, 10, 29.5, 5, 7, 15), 
                       by = c("by.1", "by.1","by.1","by.2","by.2","by.2"))

      
      mycols <- c("#92d050", "#57d3ff", "#ffc000")
      
      df <- df %>%
        arrange(desc(len)) %>%
        mutate(fills = ifelse(row_number() <= length(mycols), mycols, "grey50"))
      
      ggplot(data = df, aes(x = len, y = reorder(dose, len))) +
        geom_col(aes(fill = I(fills)))+
        geom_text(aes(x = len/2, label = glue::glue("{dose} ({len}%)"))) +
        theme_minimal() +
        ## remove expansion and x title
        scale_x_continuous(NULL, expand = c(0,0)) +
        # remove the y bits
        theme(axis.ticks.y = element_blank(), 
              axis.title.y = element_blank(), 
              axis.text.y = element_blank())
    })
    
    
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest using `multiple = TRUE` for your `selectInput` - also note the `filter()` call:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(shinyWidgets)

DF <- data.frame(dose = c("D0.5", "D1", "D2", "D3", "D4", "D5"),
                 len = c(4.2, 10, 29.5, 5, 7, 15), 
                 by = c("by.1", "by.1","by.1","by.2","by.2","by.2"))

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Plot By by"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel( width = 2, selectizeInput(inputId = "by", 
                                         label = "dataset by",
                                         choices = c("by.1", "by.2"), 
                                         selected = "by.1",
                                         multiple = TRUE,
                                         options = list('plugins' = list('remove_button')))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({

    mycols <- c("#92d050", "#57d3ff", "#ffc000")
    
    DF <- DF %>%
      arrange(desc(len)) %>%
      mutate(fills = ifelse(row_number() <= length(mycols), mycols, "grey50")) %>% filter(by %in% input$by)
    
    ggplot(data = DF, aes(x = len, y = reorder(dose, len))) +
      geom_col(aes(fill = I(fills)))+
      geom_text(aes(x = len/2, label = glue::glue("{dose} ({len}%)"))) +
      theme_minimal() +
      ## remove expansion and x title
      scale_x_continuous(NULL, expand = c(0,0)) +
      # remove the y bits
      theme(axis.ticks.y = element_blank(), 
            axis.title.y = element_blank(), 
            axis.text.y = element_blank())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: result]

PS: as an alternative to the `selectizeInput` please check [shinyWidgets::pickerInput](https://dreamrs.github.io/shinyWidgets/#select-picker) with its *select/deselect all* option.